# How can add Laravel Helper in Vue js Inertia JS

Tags: laravel, vue.js, helper, inertiajs

Good day
I Beginner in **Inertia Js** and **Vue Js** i have one **Helper** for **Laravel** normally I use this code in .blade Laravel and working `Helper::reaction_count($id,$reaction)` but in Inertia Js i thing must passed everything from controller , can help me , how i can add Helper code in .vue theme ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass object to Javascript from laravel directly then you can use `laracasts/utilities` package.

```
composer require laracasts/utilities
```

Then add a line in config/app.php

```
// config/app.php

'providers' => [
    '...',
    'Laracasts\Utilities\JavaScript\JavaScriptServiceProvider'
];
```

You can pass object to javascript like this

```
use JavaScript;

public function index()
{
    JavaScript::put([
        'count' => Helper::reaction_count($id,$reaction)
    ]);
    ...
}
```

For more information, please check here
https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer

Comment: Thanks very much @devcrazy , i read doc and use code in controller and Vue theme but give me error `{{console.log(count)}}`
Best regards

Comment: `console.log` is a javascript function, not a server side function, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks very much @devcrazy but i thing this package no good for for this job
Best regards